# Finding marginal density from probability generating function of two random variables X and Y

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Given the probability generating function of two random variables $(X,Y)$ as $G_{X,Y} (u,v)$, how to find the marginal densities of X and Y?

Specifying the probability generating function:

$G_{X,Y} (u,v) = e^{-\lambda_{1} -\lambda_{2}-\mu + \lambda_{1} u + \lambda_{2}v + \mu uv}$

Comment: Note that $G_{X,Y}(u,v)=E(u^Xv^Y)$ hence the identities $G_{X,Y}(u,1)=E(u^X)=G_X(u)$ and $G_{X,Y}(1,v)=E(v^Y)=G_Y(v)$ give the marginals. For example, $$G_X(u)=e^{-(\lambda_1+\mu)(1-u)}$$ from which you should recognize the distribution of $X$.

Comment: Okay! Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. So, what is the distribution of $X$?